Programmatically populating GtkTreeView in Glade created UI
Background
I have a photo gallery generator written in Ruby. Configuration for each photo gallery and the generator itself are both in one YAML file. This tool already works in as a terminal tool. Now I want to create a GUI for this and I chose Gtk as the GUI library. I created rough UI in Glade and I have classes both for Gtk::ApplicationWindow and Gtk::Application. When I run the Ruby code the UI created in Glade really loads / displays. Now I am a bit stuck with populating GTKTreeView, which I want to use to display the config data for a user to make last adjustments before generating the galleries.
I pushed the code I have so far — https://gitlab.com/lipoqil/static-photo-gallery-builder/-/compare/master...gui
What I've tried
I found a lot of examples in C, but those usually don't deal with classes, so those are useless for me.
I also found examples in Ruby which are not using Glade and are building the whole UI programmatically by creating manually instances of Gtk classes and naturally those then have the reference in a variable.
I found a few videos of doing something similar in Python, but those were just attaching actions to buttons, so they didn't need the reference to a specific element in the UI.
Question
How do I get reference to the GTKTreeView / GTKListStore so I can populate it?
What I imagine is I need to call .get_object('<id I've set in Glade>') on something, but have no idea on what.
In case it is not clear from "What I've tried"… I am not looking for example in C or example where the whole UI is done programmatically.
Tools used

Ruby ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [arm64-darwin23]
Glade 3.40.0 (from Homebrew on macOS)
Gtk 3.24.41 (from Homebrew on macOS, using Gtk 3 because Glade is not compatible with Gtk 4)
Gtk gem gtk3 (4.2.2) (from ruby gems)


I asked ChatGPT 4 and I got a working answer.
What I was probably looking for was bind_template_child. You give it an ID from the Glade view and after initialisation of the window class, it becomes an instance variable.
module StaticPhotoGalleryGenerator
  module GUI
    class ApplicationWindow < Gtk::ApplicationWindow
      type_register

      class << self
       
        def init
          # Set the template from the resources binary
          set_template resource: '/cz/rooland/static-photo-gallery-generator/ui/application_window.glade'
          bind_template_child('config_store1')
          bind_template_child('generate_button')
        end
      end

      def initialize(application)
        super application: application

        puts @config_store1.inspect # #<Gtk::ListStore:0x00000001437d1998 ptr=0x0000600000de20b0>
      end
    end
  end
end

I'll mark this as the answer, but I'll check this question time to time if a human didn't come up with a better solution ;)

Glad you got it working and thank you for at least writing your own answer. ChatGPT answers are technically banned from SO (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) so maybe just edit that part out ¯\(ツ)/¯

It seems to me only the AI copy pasta is prohibited, because it was building up the bloat. I had conversation with ChatGPT and then wrote the answer myself based on the code inspiration I got from that chat. I wrote the final code myself too.
